# Getting variable OUT of jquery.each() function

Tags: jquery

I have the following search function:

```
function filter() {
    $("table#list tr").each(function () {
        var search = $("#search").val();
        var name = $(this).find("span.name").html();
        var email = $(this).find("span.email").html();
        var ref = $(this).find("span.reference").html();
        var match = false;
        var count = 0;
        if((name != undefined) && (email != undefined) && (ref != undefined)) {
            if(name.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(email.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(ref.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(match) {
                $(this).removeClass("collapse");
                count++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("collapse");
            }
        }
    }); 
    $("#result-count").html(count + " results found.");
}
```

However on the last line, `count` is undefined, because I created it inside the function.  How can I get the value outside of the $.each function?

Edit: I also just realized I'm resetting the count inside the loop so it will always = 0! How can I count the results properly?

Comment: put `var count = 0;` outside `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `count` outside the `each` block. Also note that you can tidy up the logic a little too:

```
var count = 0;

$("table#list tr").each(function () {
  var search = $("#search").val();
  var name = $(this).find("span.name").html();
  var email = $(this).find("span.email").html();
  var ref = $(this).find("span.reference").html();

  if (name == undefined || email == undefined || ref == undefined)
    return;

  if (name.indexOf(search) >= 0 || email.indexOf(search) >= 0 || ref.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
    $(this).removeClass("collapse");
    count++;
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("collapse");
  }
}); 

$("#result-count").html(count + " results found.");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, just have it off the each loop:

```
function filter() {
   var count =0; // put it here
$("table#list tr").each(function () {
    var search = $("#search").val();
    var name = $(this).find("span.name").html();
    var email = $(this).find("span.email").html();
    var ref = $(this).find("span.reference").html();
    var match = false;
    if((name != undefined) && (email != undefined) && (ref != undefined)) {
        if(name.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
        if(email.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
        if(ref.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
        if(match) {
            $(this).removeClass("collapse");
            count++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("collapse");
        }
    }
}); 
$("#result-count").html(count + " results found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter() {
    var count = 0;
    $("table#list tr").each(function () {
        var search = $("#search").val();
        var name = $(this).find("span.name").html();
        var email = $(this).find("span.email").html();
        var ref = $(this).find("span.reference").html();
        var match = false;
        if((name != undefined) && (email != undefined) && (ref != undefined)) {
            if(name.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(email.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(ref.indexOf(search) >= 0) match = true;
            if(match) {
                $(this).removeClass("collapse");
                count++;
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("collapse");
            }
        }
    }); 
    $("#result-count").html(count + " results found.");
}
```